# get entity from user name FosuserBundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i have entity Collab that extend from Fos\UserBundle\Model\User, i want to get the entity from the username that i login .
 i my controller :

```
      echo $this->getUser();
    $collab->get('collab.collaborateurservice')->findCollaborateurByUserName($this->getUser());
    echo $this->getEmailCollaborateur();
```

in my manager i defined i method :

```
   public function findCollaborateurByUserName ($username){
    return $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(array('username'=>$username));
}
```

i get this exception :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
```

how can get this entity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this lines:

```
return $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(array('username'=>$username));
$collab->get('collab.collaborateurservice')->findCollaborateurByUserName($this->getUser());
```

It should be:

```
return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundleNamespace:Collab')->findOneBy(array('username'=>$username));
$collab = $this->get('collab.collaborateurservice')->findCollaborateurByUserName($this->getUser()->getUsername());
```

Comment: i use this:
 
      $col = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MytestBundle:Collaborateur')->find($this->getUser()->getId());

to get id of the user connected i used : $this->getUser()->getId().

thank you and sorry for this late answer

Answer (score 0):

What is `$collab`? You're getting Fatal Error trying to call `get` method on variable that was not properly initialized (non-object).